# How to get admin roles that I am a member of, from Microsoft Graph using .Net Client SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I know how to get member directory roles filtering by type using the rest query below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.directoryRole
```

So the response from MS Graph api only contains `directoryRole` objects. Not sure how this can be done using the MS Graph .Net client SDK as we do not specify any OData keyword like `Select` or `Filter` in the actual Rest request.

Note that I do not want to call just `memberOf` and filter `directoryRole` type responses in memory on client side, I want this filter to be part of the query as in the URL above, so `memberOf` response contains only `directoryRole` s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the SDK, filtering is a function applied to the object. For example:

```
var users = await graphClient
    .Users
    .Request()
    .Filter("startswith(displayName,'A')")
    .GetAsync();
```

Unfortunately, this won't help you here since `/memberOf` doesn't support `$filter`. So you would need to do the filtering on the client.

If you're checking a specific [`directoryRole`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/directoryrole), you could come at this from the other direction. The [`/members`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryrole_list_members) endpoint *does* support filtering by member `id`:

```
v1.0/directoryRoles/{role-id}/members?$filter=id eq '{user-id}'
```

It is important to note here that `/members` does *not* support filtering by `userPrincipalName`, only by the actual `id`.

Answer (score 1):

The Graph Net Client have not directly support your requirement.

But based on my test, we can try the following work around:

Use the following code to get the list with DirectoryRole and then filter by DisplayName, and then check the **role template id**(For the directoryRole from **Me.MemberOf**, if the DisplayName contains **Administrator**, basically, we are admin role. If use the **DirectoryRoles** api, we can iterate the list and check the **role template id**):

```
// This will contains the group too, we need to filter it to get the directoryrole

    IUserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesRequest builder = graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request();
                    IUserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage page = await builder.GetAsync();

    // This is all directoryrole in our tenant, we need to filter by DisplayName contains **Administrator**
                IGraphServiceDirectoryRolesCollectionRequest request = graphClient.DirectoryRoles.Request();
                IGraphServiceDirectoryRolesCollectionPage directoryRoles = await request.GetAsync();
```

Results of **Me.MemberOf**:
[image]
Results of **DirectoryRoles**:
[image]

If the work around still cannot suit your requirement, I suggest you submit an feature request on [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and [github issues](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues)

**Supplementary answer:**
(Unfortunately the filtering is generally pretty limited in Microsoft Graph for directory resources. So you can just use the client side in-memory filter or submit feature request now)：

Theoretically, we can use the rest api like this(**The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported.**)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:roleTemplateId eq  '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10')
```

And in the C# code which is based on the Graph Client

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
                {
                    new QueryOption("$filter", 
                      "groupTypes/any(a:roleTemplateId eq  '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10'")
                };   
IUserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesRequest builder = graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request(options); 

                    IGraphServiceDirectoryRolesCollectionRequest request = graphClient.DirectoryRoles.Request(options);
```

Comment: Is there any other way to filter a specific directoryRole from the memberOf response using the RoleTemplateId ?

Comment: I think RoleTempateId can used for filtering the result of MemberOf and DirectoryRoles(Iterating over the list or by LINQ). The way besides RoleTemplateId still need to test

Comment: If you post a working example filtering with RoleTemplateId I will accept that answer.

Comment: It is our Saturday now, I will do it in our Monday after back to office.

Comment: I should go back to my office in about 20 hours, as early as this evening.

Comment: Thanks Seiya, no major rush on this we can wait till over the weekend. Just to clarify I am not looking for an in memory filtering on client side. I know how this can be done easily. I am looking for a way to push this filtering (ie. filter by a specific RoleTemplateId) to the server side.

Comment: For server side filter, all I can say is try as possible as i can. As you know, we can do little for the Graph server side code. The most likely result, we need to do in-memory filter or submit the feature request